# Binomial Coefficients. Recursion tree. How to avoid calculating same values multiple times

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binomial-coefficients

I am working with my program called **BinomialCoefficients**.

I did a box trace on `C(5,3)` and it returns `10` which is correct, but I noticed that in my full recursion tree for `C(5, 3)`, the value `C(3, 2)` is evaluated 2 times, and `C(2, 1)` is evaluated 3 times.

What could be a modification so it avoids computing the same values multiple times?

Here is just the function to show context.

```
public static int C(int n, int k) {
   if(k>n)
      return 0;
   else if(k==0 || k==n)
      return 1;
   else
      return C(n-1, k-1)+C(n-1, k);
  }
```

Comment: Can you share the output that makes you believe that the C method is called multiple times, as well as the code where you call C?

Comment: @nhouser9 `C(10,4) = C(9,3)+C(9.4); C(9,3) = C(8,2)+C(8,3); C(9,4) = C(8,3)+C(8,4)` and just looking at these terms, you're computing `C(8,3)` twice.

Answer (score 1):

One modification would be to use the [multiplicative formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Multiplicative_formula). But you'd have to consider integer overflow....
(*Edit:* Have a look at what @**ajb** said in the comment)

I'd suggest using a Map for caching result:

```
Map<String, Integer> cache = new HashMap<>();    

public static int C(int n, int k) {
  String cacheKey=key(n,k);
  if (cache.containsKey(cacheKey){
    return cache.get(cacheKey);
  if(k>n)
    return 0;
  else if(k==0 || k==n)
    return 1;
  else {
    int result = C(n-1, k-1)+C(n-1, k);
    cache.put(cacheKey, result);
    return result ;
}

public String key(int n, int k){
  return n +"_"+k;
}
```

Of course using strings as keys is not the most efficient way, but I'd guess it's still way faster than recalculating the same value over and over again.

Comment: If you use the multiplicative formula in the right order, you probably don't have to worry too much about overflow.  Alternate divisions and multiplications like this: `n / 1 * (n-1) / 2 * (n-2) / 3 * (n-3) / 4 * ... * (n - k + 1) / k`.  All of the divisions will produce exact results with no remainder.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to rebuild Pascal's triangle from the top each time, using loops instead of recursion.  You will probably be performing some additions you don't need.  I'm not sure how many.  It would be an interesting exercise to figure out how many `C(i,j)` you'd be computing that your recursive function doesn't need.  I'm guessing that no more than half of the computed values would be unnecessary, on average, so it should still be faster than a recursive method that recomputes the same values repeatedly, and it might be faster than using a hash table, which carries its own overhead.

You should be able to compute each row "in place" without allocating a new array for each row, to make it as efficient as possible.  Say you're computing `C(12,3)`; the 13th row of the triangle will have 13 elements, so you can allocate an array of length 13 to start with, and use the first `N` elements of the array when computing the Nth row.  Say you've computed the 5th row, so the array will be

```
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1, x, x, ...]  // don't care about the x's
```

The algorithm to compute the next row would work something like this:

- Save 1 in a temporary variable.
- Save 4 in a temporary variable, and replace 4 with 4 + 1 (the previous value of the temporary variable).
- Save 6 in a temporary variable, and replace 6 with 6 + 4 (the previous value of the temporary variable)
- Save 4 in a temporary variable, and replace 4 with 4 + 6 (the previous value.... I think you can figure out how this is going to play out)